# jquery .change() method not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, file

I am trying to upload files.The thing is that When the user click submit button before choosing the file,user should get any alert.If files is already selected,the value of `submit`button should change to `Updating...`.For this I have used the `change()` method,but it is not working properly.

`javascript` file:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    { 
      var file_name='';
      //for checking whether the file queue contain files or not
      $('#upload').click(function()
      { 
       $('#file').live('change',function(){
           for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++)
           {
           file_name =  this.files[i].name; 
           //alert(file_name); 
            if(file_name !== null && file_name !== undefined)
            {
                $('#upload').attr('value','Updating..');
            } 
            else
            {
                alert('error');
            }  
           }//end for loop
       }); 
    });
}); 

html:

<form id='file-form' action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" ><br>
<input type="button" name="upload" id='upload' value="Upload file">
</form>
```

please help me.

Comment: Place your `change` event handler out of upload `click` event handler. Your event `change` will bind the handler when you click at the upload button.

Comment: .live is deprecated now.Use .on instaed

Comment: Its not working yet.@samitha

Comment: to check if the queue contains files you can just check if the attribute value is not empty `$('#file').attr("value") != ""`

Comment: what are you getting in console?

Comment: @SIBHIS S Now it shows Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ?load=portal/filesharing:71
(anonymous function) ?load=portal/filesharing:71
o.event.handle jquery.1.3.2.js:19
(anonymous function)

Comment: try type(file_name) !== 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

As per JQuery documentation .live is deprecated use on method.

```
$('#file').on('change',function(){
       //your code
   });
```

try this one

Answer (score 0):

You initialised file_name to ''. Yet in your comparison you are checking whether it is equal to null or undefined, neither of which would be true when unset.

Instead of:

```
if(file_name !== null && file_name !== undefined)
```

you are probably looking for:

```
if (file_name !== '')
```